# Rails 4, Active Record, create order scope on belongs_to for has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following models set up:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :location_parking_locations
  has_many :parking_locations, through: :location_parking_locations
end

class LocationParkingLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :parking_location
end

class ParkingLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_parking_locations
  has_many :locations, through: :location_parking_locations
end
```

The `LocationParkingLocation` has an integer field called `upvotes`. I would like to create a 'by_votes' scope that I can add to a query to order the results by this `upvotes` field. Where and how do I define this scope, so that I can call it like this:

```
location.parking_locations.by_votes
```

I can't define it like this, because then it's not a valid method on `parking_locations`:

```
class LocationParkingLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :parking_location
  scope :by_votes, -> { order("upvotes DESC") }
end
```

Should it be defined in the 'ParkingLocation' class? If so, how do I tell it that I want to order by a field on the `location_parking_locations` table?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to use [merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) here.

You can leave your scope in the `LocationParkingLocation` class, and the result would look like:

```
location.parking_locations.merge(LocationParkingLocation.by_votes)
```

I just read a little about it in [this blog post](https://coderwall.com/p/9xk6ra/rails-filter-using-join-model-on-has_many-through).